# Can't save PDF file in the Angular app in production because of the Content Security Policy directive

Tags: angular, pdf, content-security-policy, production, policy

I have the Angular app. And there is a function that saves a pdf file.

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake';
...

  createPdf(): void {

    let docDefinition = {  
      header: 'C#Corner PDF Header',  
      content: 'Simple pdf file'  
    };  
   
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('a.pdf'); 
  }
```

It worked well both locally and in production in the past. But from some point, it started to fail in production while locally everything remained the same.

This is the error I receive in the production

> ERROR EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
> 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

[image]

Is there an error in the function itself? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your security is probably checking embedded scripts in pdfs now, which can happen. I would suggest downloading the pdf as a data-url, this will appear like a stream of characters and hopefully will work around this security measure. This contains information on how to do that: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/198

Comment: seems it's related to `restructure` library .. see this https://github.com/foliojs/restructure/issues/44

Comment: @PeterS I've tried it. The result was the same.

Comment: @BenzaraTahar is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

`pdfmake` lib has a lot of unsafe-eval expressions: [eval()](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/dev-playground/server.js) and [new Function()](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/master/build/pdfmake.js) calls. Therefore if you use Content Security Policy (CSP), you have to use `'unsafe-eval'` token in the `script-src` directive.
But, apparently, you didn't bother with CSP, so it came as a surprise to you.

Most likely on production server you are using middleware like Helmet. Helmet 3 has CSP "Off" by default, but Helmet 4 swith it "On". Therefore you janen't any troubles in the past, but after upgrade NodeJS dependasies, you now have got Helmet 4 with default CSP `script src 'self'`.

You have 2 opts:

- disable CSP in [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/)
- configure CSP via [`helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)`](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet#user-content-reference) and add `'unsafe-eval'` token into `script-src` directive. May need to add other sources / keys as well if you are using external scripts / styles / fonts, but so far there is no other CSP violations.

Note: About Helmet 4 it's just guess, probably you use other middleware, which publishes a CSP HTTP response header.